# NodeJS - Cannot set Headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, knex.js

So I've searched around and found out that to fix the said issue, I have to return after sending a response. But my problem is, even though I have return, I still have the error.

```
const dbEditCourse = (req, res, db, logger) => {
    let {
        origCourse, code, description, type
    } = req.body;
    if (!code || !description || !type) {
        res.json({
            haveEmpty: true
        });
        return;
    }
    db.transaction((trx) => {
            db.select('*').from('course_strand').where('code', '=', code)
                .then(data => {
                    if (data[0]) {

                        //error happens in this block of code
                        res.json({
                            isSuccess: false
                        });
                        return;
                        //i also tried return res.json({ isSuccess: false });

                    }
                    //wrapping this in 'else' also does not work
                    return db('course_strand')
                        .returning('*')
                        .where('code', '=', origCourse)
                        .update({ code, description, type })
                })
                .then(course => {
                    return db('activity_logs')
                        .returning('*')
                        .insert({
                            date: new Date(),
                            employee_id: req.session.emp_id,
                            module: "COURSE / STRAND",
                            activity: "EDIT"
                        })
                })
                .then(activity => {
                    if (activity[0]) {
                        res.json({
                            isSuccess: true
                        });
                        return;
                    } else {
                        res.json({
                            isSuccess: false
                        });
                        return;
                    }
                })
                .then(trx.commit)
                .catch(err => {
                    logger.error(err);
                    trx.rollback;
                    res.render('pages/error-500');
                });
        })
        .catch(err => logger.error(err));
}

module.exports = {
    dbEditCourse
}
```

What I'm doing to produce the error is, If the record is existing, it will go into the block of code above. Aside from that specific block of code, I don't encounter the error elsewhere. And the code is working fine even though I have the error.

Comment: You are using multiple returns. that's why you are getting an error. just use one return. like one in `.then` and one in `.catch`. that's all.

Comment: else better way is to use async-await. how to !? please google it :)

Comment: Just now, I tried using a single return, but still no luck.

Comment: Please update your code in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot break a promise chain with return keyword, all `.then` statements will be executed (exclude you throw an error in a `.then`), the `res.json` has been called many times.

Handler all errors (include your error and system error) in catch block.

In catch block, check the error is throwing by you or not to return the response.

```
const dbEditCourse = (req, res, db, logger) => {
  let {
    origCourse, code, description, type
  } = req.body;
  if (!code || !description || !type) {
    res.json({
      haveEmpty: true
    });
    return;
  }

  // util throw a error
  const breakWithMyError = () => {
    throw new Error("MY_ERROR");
  }

  db.transaction((trx) => {
    db.select('*').from('course_strand').where('code', '=', code)
      .then(data => {
        if (data[0]) {

          //error happens in this block of code
          breakWithMyError();
          //i also tried return res.json({ isSuccess: false });

        }
        //wrapping this in 'else' also does not work
        return db('course_strand')
          .returning('*')
          .where('code', '=', origCourse)
          .update({ code, description, type })
      })
      .then(course => {
        return db('activity_logs')
          .returning('*')
          .insert({
            date: new Date(),
            employee_id: req.session.emp_id,
            module: "COURSE / STRAND",
            activity: "EDIT"
          })
      })
      .then(activity => {
        // revert logic, we check for error case first
        if (!activity[0]) {
          breakWithMyError();
        }
      })
      .then(trx.commit)
      .then(() => {
        // finally you can run to here without any error
        res.json({
          isSuccess: true
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // If you any error, the error comes form `breakWithMyError` or any things.
        if (err.message === "MY_ERROR") {
          // the error throw by `breakWithMyError`
          return res.json({
            isSuccess: false
          });
        }
        logger.error(err);
        trx.rollback;
        // Why you return a html page in failed case? `res.status(500).json({message: "Internal server!"});`
        res.render('pages/error-500');
      });
  })
    .catch(err => logger.error(err));
}

module.exports = {
  dbEditCourse
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a great addition to my knowledge, that you cannot actually break a promise. In regards with `res.render('pages/error-500');`, I actually want to display a custom-made page for error 500

Comment: Agreeing with @hoangdv, I would also recommend separating the data update function from the web response. Basically return the success/failure from the data function, then use a separate function to build the web response based on that returned value. Then it's simple to test the data function, and you can use a data function stub to test the web request/response function.

Answer (score 0):

```
const dbEditCourse = (req, res, db, logger) => {
    let {
        origCourse, code, description, type
    } = req.body;
    if (!(code && description && type)) {
        res.json({
            haveEmpty: true
        });
        return;
    } else { // Please Try this. 
        db.transaction((trx) => {
            db.select('*').from('course_strand').where('code', '=', code)
                .then(data => {
                    if (data[0]) {

                        //error happens in this block of code
                        res.json({
                            isSuccess: false
                        });
                        return;
                        //i also tried return res.json({ isSuccess: false });

                    }
                    //wrapping this in 'else' also does not work
                    return db('course_strand')
                        .returning('*')
                        .where('code', '=', origCourse)
                        .update({ code, description, type });
                })
                .then(course => {
                    return db('activity_logs')
                        .returning('*')
                        .insert({
                            date: new Date(),
                            employee_id: req.session.emp_id,
                            module: "COURSE / STRAND",
                            activity: "EDIT"
                        });
                })
                .then(activity => {
                    if (activity[0]) {
                        res.json({
                            isSuccess: true
                        });
                        return;
                    } else {
                        res.json({
                            isSuccess: false
                        });
                        return;
                    }
                })
                .then(trx.commit)
                .catch(err => {
                    logger.error(err);
                    trx.rollback;
                    res.render('pages/error-500');
                });
        })
        .catch(err => logger.error(err));
    }

};

module.exports = {
    dbEditCourse
};
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work because, I just realized that you cannot break a promise, instead, you can throw an error.