# Chaining more than one promise function in Node.js for mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

There is a requirement, that review can be added only when product and user both are found. So i have written code in order to implement this scenario.

```
User.findById(req.params.userId).exec()
        .then(response => {
            console.log("response", response);
            if (response) {
                return Product.findById(req.params.productId).exec();
            }
            else {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    message: 'User not found'
                })
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log("response", response);
            if (!response) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    message: 'Product not found'
                })
            }

            const review = new Review({
                _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                rev: req.body.rev,
                productId: req.params.productId,
                userId: req.params.userId
            });

            return review.save();

        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log("responseeeeeeee", response);
            res.status(201).json({
                response
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("error", error);
            res.status(500).json({
                error
            })
        })
```

This is working fine, but as soon as product or user is missing it is throwing a warning as such :

```
(node:17276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\backup-learning\project-shop-always\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\backup-learning\project-shop-always\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (D:\backup-learning\project-shop-always\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at User.findById.exec.then.then.then.catch.error (D:\backup-learning\project-shop-always\api\controllers\review-controller.js:58:29)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: You cannot break a promise chain with return keyword, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56033671/nodejs-cannot-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client/56034369#56034369

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the chain continues with the return value of `res.status` as the fulfillment value when you do `return res.status(/*...*/)` from within the `then` callback.

You can't use a single chain for this. Also, since you need to locate both the user and the product, probably best to do that bit in parallel. See comments:

```
// *** Start both the product and user search in parallel
Promise.all([
    User.findById(req.params.userId).exec(),
    Product.findById(req.params.productId).exec()
])
.then(([user, product]) => {
    // *** Handle it if either isn't found
    if (!user) {
        res.status(404).json({
            message: 'User not found'
        });
    } else if (!product) {
        res.status(404).json({
            message: 'Product not found'
        });
    } else {
        // *** Both found, do the review
        const review = new Review({
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            rev: req.body.rev,
            productId: req.params.productId,
            userId: req.params.userId
        });
        // *** Return the result of the save operation
        return review.save()
        .then(response => {
            console.log("responseeeeeeee", response);
            res.status(201).json({
                response
            });
        }
    }
    // *** Implicit return of `undefined` here fulfills the promise with `undefined`, which is fine
})
.catch(error => {
    // *** An error occurred finding the user, the product, or saving the review
    console.log("error", error);
    res.status(500).json({
        error
    })
});
```

If you're doing this in any modern version of Node.js, you can use an `async` function and `await`:

```
// *** In an `async` function
try {
    const [user, product] = await Promise.all([
        User.findById(req.params.userId).exec(),
        Product.findById(req.params.productId).exec()
    ]);
    if (!user) {
        res.status(404).json({
            message: 'User not found'
        });
    } else if (!product) {
        res.status(404).json({
            message: 'Product not found'
        });
    } else {
        // *** Both found, do the review
        const review = new Review({
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            rev: req.body.rev,
            productId: req.params.productId,
            userId: req.params.userId
        });
        const response = await review.save();
        console.log("responseeeeeeee", response);
        res.status(201).json({
            response
        });
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
    res.status(500).json({
        error
    })
}
```

Note that the entire code is wrapped in a `try`/`catch`, so the `async` function this is in will never reject (unless the `console.log` or `res.send` in the `catch` block raised errors), so it won't result in an unhandled rejection warning if you just make your Express endpoint handler `async` (whereas normally passing an `async` function into something that isn't expecting to receive a promise is an anti-pattern). (If you want to be a bit paranoid, wrap the contents of the `catch` block in another `try`/`catch`.)

Comment: its exactly what i was looking for. Thanks :)